# How to get a user's location based on their IP address?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, ip-address

To get the user's IP I'm using:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I have a geo database with the following tables:

```
blocks
locations
zipcodes
nations
dma_codes
states
```

This is the table I'm interested in

### blocks

```
start_ip | end_ip | location_id
-------------------------------

33996344 | 33996351 | 16373
50331648 | 67166463 | 223

etc...
```

Above are just the first 2 records of the 1,866,401 rows in total in that table. I have no idea which geo database this is. Maybye MaxMind but not sure. I inherited this project from the client's previous developer who uploaded this database but didn't do anything with it yet. So I have no code samples to go on.

Can anyone please explain how I would get the `location_id` if my ip address happens to be:

```
72.63.83.41
```

Also does anyone recognize these table names so maybye I can find out which geo db this is.

Comment: Thinking logically, you'd need to remove the dots from the ip and then do a `SELECT location_id FROM blocks WHERE start_ip <= $your_ip AND end_ip >= $your_ip;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPv4 addresses are just 32bit integers, and you can use MySQL to convert a 'string' IP address to/from those ints via `inet_ntoa()` (number to ascii) and `inet_aton()` (ascii to number).

```
SELECT location_id
FROM yourtable
WHERE INET_ATON('70.63.83.41') BETWEEN start_ip AND end_ip
```

would give you any matching location_id for that particular IP.